# How to change config to configDirectory of checkstyle Plugin in gradle 7.1.1?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have read in the documentation that config has been changed to configDirectory in checkstyle Plugin - gradle 7.1.1. But config has parameters of file type, whereas configDirectory has DirectoryProperty.

Gradle 6 - **build.gradle**

```
String path = "/abc/xyz";
apply plugin : 'checkstyle'

checkstyle { 
    config file(path) 
}
```

How do I convert the path to a directoryProperty? i.e., how do I write the same in gradle 7.1.1

I tried the same,

```
String path = "/abc/xyz";
apply plugin : 'checkstyle'

checkstyle { 
    configDirectory file(path) 
}
```

But I'm getting this error, while running gradle build,

Could not find method configDirectory() for arguments [.... path...] on extension 'checkstyle' of type org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.CheckstyleExtension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`configDirectory`'s type is `DirectoryProperty`, which extends `org.gradle.api.provider.Property`. These objects can be set by calling the `set` method:

```gradle
...

tasks.withType(Checkstyle).configureEach {
    configDirectory.set(file("/abc/xyz"))
}
```

Personally, I will check the IntelliJ's auto-completion hints and Gradle's Javadoc.

#### References:

- https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/plugins/quality/CheckstyleExtension.html

Answer (score 0):

Or just simple use next code snippet

```
checkstyle {
   configDirectory = file("/abc/xyz")
}
```

**Reference:**
https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.CheckstyleExtension.html